# React-Redux adding element to list causes render of all elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my React/Redux App I have a list of objects that I render in my Dashboard.
I'm periodically updating that list: to simplify I made a test using the following action in my reducer (in which `action.payload` is the object to add).

```
case Actions.SET_TERMINAL_LIST:
  return {
    ...state,
    terminalList: [
       ...state.terminalList,
       action.payload
    ]
  }
```

Despite I'm just adding an object to the list without muting the others, the update is causing a re-render of every element in the list.
Is this the normal behaviour?

I'm trying to look for a consistent solution, I'd really avoid using `shouldComponentUpdate` to condition the update. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Maybe use react pure component, it manage the shouldComponentUpdate for you https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

Comment: If you're using functional components, you can make use of useMemo to improve performance.

Comment: Yes, React ***must*** rerender the entire ReactTree in order to determine what possibly changed. Note that this occurs in the virtual DOM ***and not*** when a component is rendered out to the DOM. What/where/how are you determining that anything is "rerendering"? Depending on your answer will be a likely explanation.

Comment: @DrewReese the render is closing a Modal opened clicking on a Button inside the rendered element. The update in redux is also resetting the :hover css function for a short but annoying moment.